# Setting Microsoft HPC-Cluster dates to ISO-format

Tags: windows, rest, datetime-format, hpc

When I query job properties with

```
https://hpc-cluster/WindowsHPC/cluster_name/Job/573374?Properties=CreateTime
```

the response uses a locale date format:

```
<Property><Name>ChangeTime</Name><Value>28.11.2016 08:24:06</Value></Property>
```

But filtering jobs needs ISO-format `2016-11-28T10:06:37Z`:

```
https://hpc-cluster/WindowsHPC/cluster_name/Jobs?%24filter=ChangeTimeFrom%20eq%202016-11-28T15%3A06%3A37Z&Render=RestPropRender
```

How can I configure the response to use ISO-format all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't !

Because according to the [Microsoft documentation relative to job properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.scheduler.properties.jobpropertyids_members(v=vs.85).aspx), most precisely [ISchedulerJob.CreateTime Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.scheduler.properties.jobpropertyids.createtime(v=vs.85).aspx) & [ISchedulerJob.ChangeTime Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.scheduler.ischedulerjob.changetime(v=vs.85).aspx):

For both properties:

> The value is in Coordinated Universal Time.

You may convert your UTC time to ISO date somewhere in your code.

*Did you also notice in your example that you ask for "CreateTime", but response show, the property "ChangeTime" ...*